# Disable write to ext4 after memory modification

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm trying to modify user space application code in run-time from a Linux kernel driver.

Given the following code snippet:

```
writeCR3(process_cr3);
writeCR0(cr0 & ~X86_CR0_WP); // to allow writing to RO pages
*(char*)someUserAddress = 0x90; // just an example, nop
writeCR0(cr0 | X86_CR0_WP); // restore write protection
```

it successfully modifies the user application code in run-time but for some reason the file it self also changes (If I use 'OBJDUMP' or 'READELF' on the modified executable file after writing I can actually see that it has been modified) - it seems that it is getting written into the ext4 file system as well.

I do not want that. I want the code to be modified only inside the memory.
How do I achieve that? and why does the file system actually modify the file it self as well?

Comment: That is because page related to a binary image and thus considered to be "Page Cache". When you write an address, processor sets "Dirty" bit on entry, while vmscan (?) sets corresponding Dirty bit in page structure. All dirty "Page Cache" pages are written back to disk. I do not see clean solution for that. Probably, you may permanently mark page as not cached by setting PG_swapbacked flag to it, but consequences to that are unpredictable.

Comment: Is there any hardware mechanism for that ?

Comment: Why are you trying to modify user space code from the kernel in the first place? Sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).